# Retrieve id of div from within a get()

Tags: javascript, html, lightning-web-components, get

In my lightning web component I am trying to loop through a an array they determines if an item in a combobox should be marked or not:

HTML

```
<ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
    <template for:each={roleOptions} for:item="role">
        <li key={role.name} data-key={role.name} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" onclick={toggleRolesFilterSelection} >
            <div id={role.name} class={rolesSelectionClass} role="option"> <<< THIS LINE
                <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon">
                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-check slds-current-color">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                                <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                </span>
                <span class="slds-media__body">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title={role.name}>{role.name}</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

On the 4th line you will see `<div id={role.name} class={rolesSelectionClass} role="option">`and then in my JS this is my `rolesSelectionClass`:

JS

```
roleOptions = [
    { name: "limited", selected: false },
    { name: "standard", selected: true },
    { name: "premium", selected: false },
    { name: "workshop", selected: true },
]

get rolesSelectionClass(someParam) {
    var role = someParam.path.to.get.div.id
    // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
    this.roleOptions.forEach(o => {
        if (o.name === role) {
            return "slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-is-selected slds-has-focus"
        }
    })
    return "slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
}
```

Is there something similar in a `get()` to what you can do using an `onClick` handler's `event` where you can call `event.currentTarget.dataset.key` ?

Comment: Where do you define `roleOptions`? It seems like you are missing some important context here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson okay, I defined roleOptions. I didn't consider it necessary to be able to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first thing first, I believe we can not pass parameter in getters. We do this in setters.
2. Second, This is not the right way to do. Iterate this list in your JS and add a new variable to your row. such as classNames then use it on class = {role.classNames}